# How to use module `module` in a vue project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, eslint

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 6 errors                                                                                                                            16:20:36

This dependency was not found:

* module in ./node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/shared/relative-module-resolver.js, ./node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue/lib/rules/experimental-script-setup-vars.js and 4 others
```

I want to use eslint and eslint-plugin-vue directly in my vue project, but I got the above error after run serve.

How to polyfill `module` or how to resolve it? Thank you all.

Project:

1. use `vue.config.js`

Answer (score -3):

We can resolve the problem by this way:
https://github.com/ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-vue-demo

The link page refer us a demo to use eslint and eslint-plugin-vue in browser.

Configs in `vue.config.js` of project can resolve the above question:

```js
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          // resolve `module` not found
          module: path.resolve("./shim/module.js"),
          globby: path.resolve("./shim/empty"),
          eslint$: path.resolve("./shim/eslint/index.js"),
          esquery: path.resolve("./node_modules/esquery/dist/esquery.min.js"),
          "@eslint/eslintrc/universal": path.resolve(
            "./node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc-universal.cjs",
          ),
        }
      },
```

alias links to this directory:
https://github.com/ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-vue-demo/tree/main/shim

Other alias will resolve faults after resolve `module` not found happen.